# searching for a suitable synonym for " a group of people " ex. young people , old people , etc

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

I specially want to use this word after "adolescent" . better said, I'm looking for a nice paraphrasing for " young people ".

Comment: Boys and girls? ..

Comment: I'm afraid it's not what I need... what I'm looking for has to bear a much closer meaning to a word like " generation " and suchlike.

Comment: You can simply call them adolescents. (or pre-teens, tweenies, pre-pubescents, etc.)

Comment: I'm looking for a word to use after adolescent , I got no problems with adolescent itself, ex. is a collocation like " adolescent generation " a correct one? @KristinaLopez

Comment: Unfortunately, "generation" might not work because it refers to a group from a particular time period, like the post-WWII Baby Boomer generation.  Adolescents, on the other hand, are people *in* a particular phase of their lives at this time.  It's perfectly acceptable and is common usage to hang an "s" at the end of that group's description which is why you'll see reference to all the groups I mentioned in my other comment.  To add another word to force the concept of a "group" onto something already understood as such would feel forced and contrived - again, IMO.

Comment: In more academic writing, you could say "cohort."

Comment: Couldn't you just call them 'adolescents'? If you really want a following word, you could probably use 'youths'.

Comment: The adolescent lot; *Preteens; teenagers; teenyboppers* "The study intends to enlighten future research in mobile phone research and will definitely take in to account the adolescent lot ..." (ojs.uok.edu.in)

Answer (score 1):

A **bevy of adolescents** or **bevy of youths** means a group of young persons. Not exactly the kind of construction you're looking for, but it would mean the same as "an adolescent (word)".

"bevy", used most frequently with girls, women and children. I've also seen it used with reference to sailors.

> - "bevy" (noun) -  a group or assemblage: a bevy of young beach boys, a bevy of sailors, a bevy of beauties. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bevy)
> - "youth, pl youths" (noun)  young persons or creatures —usually plural in construction. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/youth)

Answer (score 0):

'battery' is a term used for group of people, usually soldiers - but it is not restricted to soldiers.  It can be used for young people - 'charged' with lot of 'energy', I would presume.

Comment: I'm very curious if you could come up with one literary example where a group of **youngsters** are described as a battery.

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/cricket/international/england/9277279/England-v-West-Indies-tourists-pacemen-offer-up-only-toil-and-not-the-terror-of-old.html - to quote 'It is England who now have the battery of pace men who can make the ball talk'.  I remember reading it - especially the phrase 'battery of pacemen' is used quite a few times in cricket.

Answer (score 0):

might the word be *moxie*: a *moxie* 
adolescent.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moxie

Answer (score 0):

**A few informal and humorous terms for groups of young people**

My personal favorite being:

> **gaggle** *noun* a group of people, especially a noisy and uncontrolled group

but then there are these:

> **bunch** *noun* a group of people
>
> **gang** *noun* a group of friends, especially young people
>
> **mob** *noun* a group of people who are connected in some way
>
> **crew** *noun* a group of people
>
> **clan** *noun* a group of people who share an interest or goal
>
> **bevy** *noun* a group of people or things of the same kind
>
> **lot** *noun* a particular group of people
>
> **posse** *noun* a group of friends (This word is mainly used by young people referring to other young people)
>
> from the [**MACMILLAN DICTIONARY**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/informal-and-humorous-words-for-groups-of-people)

Answer (score 0):

A group of people from the same generation (of same or nearly same age) are called a "cohort".

Free Dictionary
COHORT   Noun
1(c)  A generational group as defined in demographics, statistics or market research